# Use of sed with double quotation

Tags: sed, string

Answering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529950/how-to-use-awk-inside-sed):

I found the following situation with `sed` version 4.2.2.

From this input:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
```

I want to remove the string "host-name" only from the second line, so the expected output is:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search,
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
```

Then I used the following command:

```
sed -e 's/" host-name,"//g' input_file
```

However, it won't remove the " host-name," string on input_file leaving it as it was.

If I don't use double quotation:

```
sed -e 's/ host-name,//g' input_file
```

It gives properly the expected output.

I thought that the correct way would be by using double quotation, but can't figure out why it's not working here.

Comment: see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character `"` is not special for the shell inside `'`...`'`. In fact, inside `'`...`'` *no character is special* for the shell; as a consequence, the `"` characters are passed to `sed`; and they are not special to `sed`.

The command `sed -e 's/" host-name,"//g'` is looking literally for `"`    `h` `o` `s` `t` `n` `a` `m` `e` `,` `"`, which it won't find because it's not there.